# How to draw data flow graphs in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, tree, drawing

I would like to know if there is an already samples of doing data flow graphs using QT graphics API.

I would like to see some samples to get started with.

Comment: If it is still relevant https://github.com/paceholder/nodeeditor

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Qt comes with various examples that might help you get started.

The following two examples come to mind:

- The [Diagram Scene Example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-graphicsview-diagramscene-example.html)
- [Elastic Nodes Example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-graphicsview-elasticnodes-example.html)

Have a look at those for some inspiration.

Qt-based, but a separate project which is possibly more along the lines of what you're looking for is [NUKEEngine's Qt Node Editor](http://nukengine.com/qt-node-editor/).